# Block booking for particular days and month

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

```
    var pickmonth = Date.parse(pickupDate).getMonth();
    var pickday = Date.parse(pickupDate).getDay();

    if (pickday < 6 &&(pickmonth == 6 || pickmonth == 7)){

       if((parseInt(days) > parseInt(0) && parseInt(days) < parseInt(7)) ||(parseInt(days) > parseInt(7) && parseInt(days) < parseInt(14)) || (parseInt(days) > parseInt(14) && parseInt(days) < parseInt(21))){

           alert ('Hi');
           error.push(translated_strings.min_booking_days + '7,14 & 21 and checkin day must be saturday' + min_rental_days);
       }

    }
```

I want the booking in month of july and august only booking of 7,14,21 days and also booking pickday must be saturday. I am using rental and booking plugin. Its working fine for month of july and august what i want but not woking for day.
I also want booking day must be saturday. Please any help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I got the solution

Comment: if (pickmonth == 6 || pickmonth == 7){
   
   
   if((parseInt(days) > parseInt(0) && parseInt(days) < parseInt(7)) ||(parseInt(days) > parseInt(7) && parseInt(days) < parseInt(14)) || (parseInt(days) > parseInt(14) && parseInt(days) < parseInt(21))){
    
    error.push(translated_strings.min_booking_days + '7,14 & 21 and checkin day must be saturday' + min_rental_days);
   }
   
   if (pickday < 6){
    error.push(translated_strings.min_booking_days + '7,14 & 21 and checkin day must be saturday' + min_rental_days);
   }
   
   }

Comment: please post your comment as answer as this willl be in readble format

Answer (score 0):

```
var pickmonth = Date.parse(pickupDate).getMonth();
                        var pickday = Date.parse(pickupDate).getDay();

        if (pickmonth == 6 || pickmonth == 7){


        if((parseInt(days) > parseInt(0) && parseInt(days) < parseInt(7)) ||(parseInt(days) > parseInt(7) && parseInt(days) < parseInt(14)) || (parseInt(days) > parseInt(14) && parseInt(days) < parseInt(21))){

            error.push(translated_strings.min_booking_days + '7,14 & 21 and checkin day must be saturday' + min_rental_days);
        }

        if (pickday < 6){
            error.push(translated_strings.min_booking_days + '7,14 & 21 and checkin day must be saturday' + min_rental_days);
        }

        }
```

This way i got our solution.

Comment: It Works for me.